# Scala - Difference between Supervisor and Try-catch error handling strategies

Tags: scala, actorsystem

can someone explain the difference between the "supervisor"- and the "try-catch"-error handling strategies in an ActorSystem in Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try-catch can recover from `Exception` thrown within the `try` block (provided that error is reported by throwing `Exception`). It isn't tied to actors but it's an available method of dealing with errors in Scala (inherited from Java):

```
def method(arg: String): Int = try {
  arg.toInt
} catch {
  case _: Throwable => 0
}
```

Supervisor is used to decide what to do if `Exception` in our code wasn't caught or if some other error happened - which usually means some other `Exception` but not thrown nor handled by our code - transporting message from one cluster to another, invalid internal state, etc.

Try-catch is something you can use inside your own code to make sure that a method will succeed. It's very local in scope. If you cannot make such guarantee and want to tell ActorSystem what to do with an `Actor` that couldn't handle error on its own (or maybe even with a whole group of `Actor`s) then you use Supervisor - Supervisor however cannot just catch `Exception` and make sure that function will return normal value instead. It will order Actor to restart (with clearing its state or with keeping the current state), kill Actor permanently or escalate to Actor's parent.

When supervision is needed is quite [well explained in the documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/supervision.html#what-restarting-means).

Simplifying, dealing with errors on processing should be left for Actor, which internaly recovers from errors using `try`-`catch`, `Try`, etc, while Supervisor should be used with SupervisionStrategies to provide fault-tolerance [like in documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/fault-tolerance.html).